# F# modeling playing cards

Tags: f#, playing-cards

I am trying to represent [standard playing cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck) in F#. My goal is to implement a clone of [Microsoft Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Solitaire) (the one that comes with Windows) , a game in which Cards' Suit, Face, and Color are important. This exercise is mostly intended as a way to learn some F#.

I have considered using discriminated unions:

```
type Suit =
    | Diamonds
    | Hearts
    | Clubs
    | Spades

type Color =
    | Red
    | Black

type Face =
    Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven |
    Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
```

with a record type for Card:

```
type Card = {
    suit: Suit;
    face: Face;
    color: Color;
}
```

However, a Card's Color can be inferred from its Suit—all Diamonds and Hearts are Red, and all Clubs and Spades are Black. Suit cannot be determined from Color alone. Perhaps something like this is appropriate:

```
type Suit =
    | Diamonds of Color //should always be red
    | Hearts of Color //should always be red
    | Clubs of Color //should always be black
    | Spades of Color //should always be black

type Face =
    Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven |
    Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = {
    suit: Suit;
    face: Face;
}
```

But this doesn't seem right, since this allows incorrect combinations, e.g. Black Hearts and Red Spades.

My questions are:

1. What is the most idiomatic way to handle Suit and Color, considering that Color is dependent on Suit?
2. Should the concept of Color even be explicitly represented? One could theoretically just replace all occurrences of Color with pattern matches against Diamonds or Hearts (which are red) and Clubs or Spades (which are black).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `Color` can always be inferred from `Suit`, there's no reason to model it explicitly; you'll want to make [illegal states unrepresentable](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-making-illegal-states-unrepresentable).

You can still get a nice programming experience out of your model, and have a nice way of modelling colour, using an [Active Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx):

```
type Suit =
    | Diamonds
    | Hearts
    | Clubs
    | Spades

let (|Red|Black|) suit =
    match suit with
    | Diamonds | Hearts -> Red
    | Clubs | Spades -> Black
```

This would enable you to pattern match on `Suit`, like this inane example:

```
let printColor card =
    match card.Suit with
    | Red -> "Red"
    | Black -> "Black"
```

Usage example from FSI:

```
> printColor { Suit = Spades; Face = Ace };;
val it : string = "Black"
> printColor { Suit = Diamonds; Face = King };;
val it : string = "Red"
```

Comment: Active patterns are so cool and useful :) Everytime I see a cool application of them I'm in awe of how such a simple mechanic can be so useful in cleaning up code.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a recording method:

```
type Card = 
    {suit: Suit;face: Face}
    member this.Color = 
        match this.suit with
            | Diamonds | Hearts -> Red
            | Clubs | Spades -> Black
```

Example:

```
let v = {suit = Diamonds;face = Two}
printfn "%A" v.Color

let v1 = {suit = Clubs;face = Two}
printfn "%A" v1.Color
```

Red
Black
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .